# Autoclose the keyboard popupCharacters in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, popup, auto-close

I am working on a soft keyboard for android based on the sample softkeyboard (i know its old but its all i have to work on) and using code similar to the following

```
<Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popupview"
     android:popupCharacters="2\@"/>
```

When the key is long-pressed, it shows the popup but it doesn't auto-close, i have to either select a character or press on a X (close) button. How can i make it auto-close and also be able to select a character by long pressing it and sliding to the desired character, like the AOSP keyboard in android?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to hide soft keyboard

```
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not trying to hide the soft keyboard. I want the popup characters (which appear when you long press a key), to close automatically if i lift the finger.